# Single Review Approved Multiple Pull Requests

Tags: github, merge, pull-request

My organization requires approved pull requests. We currently have two active development branches that have essentially, but not literally, the same code. I'll refer to them as DevA and DevB. I built a feature (Feature) off of DevA, merged DevA into Feature, and then pushed Feature. On GitHub, I created two pull requests. The first was merging Feature into DevA, and the second was merging Feature into DevB. To my surprise, following an approval on `Feature->DevA`, I was able to merge `Feature->DevB`, despite not getting approval for that PR. I merged `Feature->DevA`, which removed the ability to merge `Feature->DevB` until I received a second approval. Why did this happen?

My theory is because `Feature` was the same for both PRs, the approval allowed my to execute *any* pull request where `Feature` is the branch getting merged in. After the first pull request completed, there was no longer an active approval for Feature, which required a second approval for `Feature->DevB`.

[image: Network Screenshot]

Comment: We'll have to see your commit graph to help with this. Feel free to redact anything sensitive, but please clearly show all of the branches.

Comment: I will try to append that to the post as soon as possible, thanks

Comment: @Chris Uploaded relevant snippet from Network view. F = Feature, Da = DevA, Db = DevB

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that image illustrates your question well enough. I can't see the relationship between `DevA`, `DevB`, and `Feature` (where they _originate_ as well as where they get merged). Generally speaking, one approval will not cause other PRs to be approved (though merging a PR _can_ cause another PR to be closed as merged, e.g. if one "includes" the other).

Comment: FWIW, DevB was branched off of DevA recently. In their current states DevA and DevB have the same code because people have been merging features with both branches. Feature originates from DevA as well. I appreciate the effort, though